# Xamarin Forms Error: Default constructor not found for type Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have been building on a Xamarin.Forms app and have just now noticed a strange issue in the App.xaml file where I am declaring the global resources in the `ResourceDirectory`. Even just after removing extra lines of space in the App.xaml file it gives this error after doing a rebuild:

> Default constructor not found for type Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource

on the first line GreekNavBarImage:

```xml
<ImageSource x:Key="GreekNavBarImage">greek_temp.png</ImageSource>
    
<ImageSource x:Key="LatinNavBarImage">latin_temp.png</ImageSource>
    
<ImageSource x:Key="CurrentNavBarImage">greek_temp.png</ImageSource>
```

[image: App.xaml screenshot]

I think the namespace it is using `xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"` is okay even though when you click on it it says it is out of date. It is still in all of the official Microsoft Xamarin docs.

I cannot find much else about this error and keep having to delete and redownload the project from
git in order to fix this anytime I even touch this file. It is becoming tedious and getting I am needing to edit this App.xaml file locally.

I have tried reading the `ImageSource` docs but it still seems like it should have a default constructor that works as it is not any custom class but just the default `Xamarin.Forms.ImageSource`.

Comment: `ImageSource` is an `abstract` class, which means it cannot be instantiated: https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.imagesource?view=xamarin-forms. You're attempting to instantiate it by using it as a static resource, which is not possible.

Comment: Try FileImageSource

Comment: Okay gotcha, so if I am needing these images set from these .png files globally would I instead need to declare them in the `App.xaml.cs` file in the `App` constructor?

Comment: @JebEly I tested the `<ImageSource x:Key="LatinNavBarImage">latin_temp.png</ImageSource>` as a global resource in the ResourceDirectory and then consume it in `XAML` like: <Image Source="{StaticResource LatinNavBarImage}"/>. It successfully compiled and showed the image.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT Hmm interesting, thanks for testing. The only reference to it is: `Current.Resources["CurrentNavBarImage"] = Current.Resources["LatinNavBarImage"];` in the `App.xaml.cs` code behind where it will then be used via the `CurrentNavBarImage`. It works and compiles like yours, showing the image too, as long as I do not edit the file in any way. It is almost as if something is wrong with the build order or something.

Comment: Gald to see it works, you can also go through the official docs:[Xamarin.Forms resource dictionaries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/resource-dictionaries).